# Teradata stored procedure

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

**i am planning to write stored procedure (teradata) with bunch of update statements in it .i want to capture number of rows updated for each update statement into an audit table .so can some one help me with SQL?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ACTIVITY_COUNT` variable within your stored procedure.  For example:

```sql
   UPDATE MyTable
   SET col1 = 'val';

   INSERT INTO MyAuditTable (ActivityCount)
   VALUES (:ACTIVITY_COUNT);
```

Keep in mind this variable is only accessible within your SP.

[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn~lAaKSORpulwFMg/uyNpbjTMZfdsna_ORNp3aw)

Comment: Thank you mr.ravioli.will try